# Embed a search form in Bootstrap 3 panel heading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to embed a search form at the right side of a panel heading:

```
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Results <span class="badge">6</span></h3>

  <form class="form-inline pull-right" role="search" method="get" action="/tbl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="criteria" class="form-control" value="<%= params[:criteria] if params[:criteria] %>" placeholder="<%= params[:criteria]? params[:criteria] : 'Enter search criteria (e.g. FOOBAR_%)' %>">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  </div>
```

Unfortunately, I'm having alignment issues:

In Safari (8.0.3):

[image]

In Firefox (35.0.1):

[image]

Is there a way to do this, preferably without custom CSS?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbodbo8c/)

Comment: Should be `input-group` instead of `form-group`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost, see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jbodbo8c/4/)

I put the heading and search box into col divs, but id have to add a little padding to he title to get it to line up with the search box

CSS:

```
.padFix{
    padding-top:8px;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="panel-heading ">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <h3 class="panel-title padFix">Results <span class="badge">6</span></h3></div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <form role="search" method="get" action="/tbl">
                    <div class="input-group">
                       <input type="text" name="criteria" class="form-control" value="<%= params[:criteria] if params[:criteria] %>" placeholder="<%= params[:criteria]? params[:criteria] : 'Enter search criteria (e.g. FOOBAR_%)' %>">
                       <div class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer assumes that I want to use JS to filter the records, correct?  At this point, I want to do a `POST` to do so.

Comment: just drop your form into the `<div class="col-sm-6">`. I dropped in a default input group since there was something wrong with yours. Let me update the fiddle...

Answer (score 2):

Here am sharing my answer, this might be useful

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bewithdhanu/9z0wozya/)

Here is the code

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <h4 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">
            Header
          </h4>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
          <input type="text" class="custom_input">
          <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" style="height: 30px;">
            Search
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Content Body
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        Content Footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.custom_input {
  padding: 4px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #d3e0e9;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-right: none;
  height: 30px;
}
```

thank You  :-)